# Как сохранить размер TextView?

Tags: android

Как сделать чтобы пользователь мог сохранить размер текста textview во всем приложении с помощью `SharedPreference-ListPreference` и в каких методах нужно это прописать `onResume()` или `onCreate()`?

Answer (score 2):

1. Сохранять нужно в `onDestroy()`
2. Сохранять нужно размер и шрифт

Где то так:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  float size=textView.getTextSize();
  Typeface typeface=textView.getTypeface();
  // и.т.д.
  //далее все эти пишем SharedPreference
}
```

Comment: а как прописать все это в SharedPreference?